# How to scan a string

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to scan a NSString to find that text: "S:027,13"
Then If the scan find the text (make a condition)

I found some explanations about NSScanner but too much developped for the "simple" thing that I'd like to do...

If someone can light my way :-)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you always looking for exactly "S:027,13", or are you looking for a string that matches some less specific criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if ([string rangeOfString:@"S:027,13"].location != NSNotFound)

Comment: Other question, in my condition I need to find if the start of the string is found: if "S:027," is found, I need to get the "13" back (because the "13" part can be an other number), how can I do that?

Comment: Probably want to split. Try something like:  NSString *searchString = @"S:027,13";
    NSArray *splitArray = [searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString *afterCommaString = [splitArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"Testing - %@", afterCommaString);

Comment: I don't want to split. the rangeOfString is an easy way to know if the "S:027," is found in my string. But if it's found, I'd like to have the number which is following the "S:027," I think that I have to take my original string and make a NSScanner object which will start with the "S:027," but I need help to return the number desired in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are looking for this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString: